# Override the RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument) method from ICallbackEventHandler interface. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, icallbackeventhandler

I need to implement the [ICallbackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.icallbackeventhandler.aspx) interface in C#, but I need slightly different logic...
The thing is, that the *RaiseCallbackEvent* method accepts string as input argument, but I need it to be say, XmlDocument, or some other not-simple data type passed from the javascipt code.

Is it possible, and what is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the signature of your method must match the interface exactly.
But you can send in [`XmlDocument.OuterXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) as the string.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. I'm doing this for project at university, so I do not have much experience. More precisely, I need to pass the google directions response --> http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Directions
from javascript asynchronous to the .net code. So, how can I perform something similar to  XmlDocument.OuterXml in Javascript?